# Three.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined when loading 3D object

Tags: json, animation, three.js, loading

```
    ob = JSON.stringify( that.char_elements[0].anim_manager.anim_list[0].obj.toJSON(), null, 3 );
    require("fs").writeFile( "./src/data/obj.pr", ob , 'utf8', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

This is how i'm writing the .json file to be loaded later. And it doesn't seem to be having any problems with the import, since the resulting file has this format:

```
{
   "metadata": {
      "version": 4.5,
      "type": "Object",
      "generator": "Object3D.toJSON"
   },
   "geometries": [
      {
         "uuid": "447BF091-8882-4377-97C0-6E5102476B59",
         "type": "BufferGeometry",
         "name": "pCylinder2.000",
         "data": {...
```

But when i'm trying to load it later using a THREE.ObjectLoader, i'll this weird error from the title from this piece of code, when i try to load it that way:

```
    var f2 = require('fs').readFileSync("./src/data/project.pr", 'utf8', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    char.anim_manager.loader_helper.js_loader.load( f2, char.anim_manager.loader_helper.true_load);
// gives this error: Three.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of 
// undefined when loading 3D object...at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.js:34342)
```

The loading function:

```
    function load_init( anim ) {
    viewer.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( anim );

    if(viewer.cur_anim)
        viewer.scene.remove(viewer.cur_anim);

    cur_anim.anim = anim;
    viewer.cur_anim = cur_anim.anim;

    var that = this;
    anim.name = "animation_name";

    var mat_dict = {};

    anim.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child.isMesh ) {

            //anim.mat_manager.mat_list
            const oldMat = child.material;

            if(oldMat.length == undefined)//only one material in the mesh
            {
                if(!mat_dict[oldMat.name])
                {
                    child.material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial( {  
                        color: oldMat.color,
                        skinning: true,
                        name: oldMat.name,
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                        shininess: 0,
                        specular: 0,
                        reflectivity: 0,
                    } ); 

                    mat_dict[oldMat.name] = child.material;
                    cur_anim.mat_manager.mat_list.push(child.material);
                }
                else
                    child.material = mat_dict[oldMat.name];
            }
            else//multiple materials
            {
                for(var i = 0; i < oldMat.length; i++)
                {
                    if(!mat_dict[oldMat[i].name])
                    {
                        child.material[i] = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial( {  
                        color: oldMat[i].color,
                        skinning: true,
                        name: oldMat[i].name,
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                        shininess: 0,
                        specular: 0,
                        reflectivity: 0,
                        } );

                        mat_dict[oldMat[i].name] = child.material[i];
                        cur_anim.mat_manager.mat_list.push(child.material[i]);
                    }
                    else
                        child.material[i] = mat_dict[oldMat[i].name];
                }
            }
        }
    } );

    var action = viewer.mixer.clipAction( anim.animations[ 0 ] );
    action.play();

    viewer.scene.add( cur_anim.anim );
}
```

But i use a bind to avoid use of **this** errors. It's called true_load

```
var true_load = load_init.bind(this);
```

Comment: Can you please share your entire JSON file?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here's the file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/h1mhyv9sydida65/obj.pr/file

Comment: I was able to load your JSON model into the `three.js` [editor](https://threejs.org/editor/). The result looks like so: https://imgur.com/a/BUqbano. So it seems `THREE.ObjectLoader` is able to load your file. You probably do something wrong in your app. Do you mind demonstrating with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/) how you load the file?

Comment: I cannot tell you **exactly** how i'm doing it because i forgot to push to git(the loading functions are all ok with the version i have) and i'm at my job atm, so no access to that pc. But basically, i have a loader helper 'class' to manage loading stuff for me. When i click a button, the json will be saved just like you saw it in the OP. Once i click on the load button, it'll read the file like you see in the OP. In the Animation manager (where i put all characters and animations) i'll call the load from there (be it a FBX or whatever) like you see it there. But the true load is as follows:

Comment: Sorry for the lack of js.fiddle, but i don't really know how to use it and right now i can't stop to give it a look. The function i'm using is in the OP